# Closing DialogDescriptor and set its value using a button inside it

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

Some of the constructors provided by Dialog API's DialogDescriptor accept JPanel as the first parameter. Is it possible to have a button **inside** this panel that triggers the Dialog closing as well as specify a return value?

I want to make such a "resolving conflict" dialog, just like how Ms Windows offers Copy/Discard/Copy Both options when we copy files from one directory but there are files with the same name in the destination directory. Note that pressing one of three buttons will close the dialog, but actually none of them is listed as closing options; the closing options itself consist of "Skip" and "Cancel".

Comment: I can't test it, but [this constructor](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-dialogs/org/openide/DialogDescriptor.html#DialogDescriptor%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.Object[) and also the last one enables you to specify the options used. You could also probably just use [`setOptions()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-dialogs/org/openide/NotifyDescriptor.html#setOptions-java.lang.Object:A-).

Comment: @LukasRotter just like stated in the doc, those `options` will appear as buttons in the **button row** of the dialog (the button row itself is part of the dialog, outside our panel). That's exactly how I set the "Skip" and "Cancel" options. What I was initially asking is how can we trigger the dialog closing by pressing a button **inside** the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try think the other way: making a panel manipulating the dialog outside of it introduces unnecessary dependency.  Why not make the dialog pass in which button is clicked when closing and have the following logic done in the panel?  You purpose is to do something when "Skip" is clicked and something else when "Cancel" is clicked, right?  So let the dialog tell your panel what's clicked instead of let the panel dispose the dialog would be less coupling.